# Device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: boot, dual-boot, acpi, 23.04

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 as a dual boot with Windows 11. Every time I select Ubuntu from grub it takes me to a screen and stays for a minute before booting up. It says `device descriptor read/64, error -110`. I have read previous questions on this issue about no proper power supply to sub, but in my case it's already installed.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste `systemd-analyze blame` command output (in text, not photo).

Comment: removing the bluetooth wifi and usb hub solved the problwm surprisingly